# Making a substring out of a line read from file

Tags: java, string, substring

So I am trying to read through a .txt file and find all instances of html tags, push opening tags to a stack, and then pop it when I find a closing tag.  Right now I am getting String out of bounds exception for the following line:

```
    if(scan.next().startsWith("</", 1))
            {
                toCompare = scan.next().substring(scan.next().indexOf('<'+2), scan.next().indexOf('>'));
                tempString = htmlTag.pop();
                if(!tempString.equals(toCompare))
                {
                    isBalanced = false;
                }
            }
            else if(scan.next().startsWith("<"))
            {
                tempString = scan.next().substring(scan.next().indexOf('<'+1), scan.next().indexOf('>'));
                htmlTag.push(tempString);
            }
```

It is telling me that the index of the last letter is -1.  The problem I can think of is that all of the scan.next() calls are moving onto the next string.  If this is the case, do I need to just write

```
    toCompare = scan.next()
```

and then so my comparisons?

Comment: Remove **`else`** operator.

Comment: If you've fixed what @Pshemo told you, then don't wonder that `str.substring(str.indexOf('<'+2), str.indexOf('>'))` will always be an empty String. And `str.indexOf('<'+1)` won't work well, if there is no `"="` in that string ...

Comment: Of course all the `scan.next()` calls are moving on to the next string. That's why the method is named *next*, to get the *next* token.

Answer (score 0):

You have two major problems in your code:

- you're calling `scan.next()` way too much and as you expect, this will move the scanner to the next token. Therefore, the last one will be lost and gone.
- `.indexOf('<'+2)` doesn't return the index of `'<'` and adds *2* to that position, it will return the index of `'>'`, because you're adding *2* to the int value of char `<` (60; `>` has 62). Your problem with index *-1* (*"It is telling me that the index of the last letter is -1."*) comes from this call: `.indexOf('<'+1)` this looks for char `'='` and if your string doesn't contain that, then it will return *-1*. A call for `#substring(int, int)` will fail if you pass *-1* as the starting position.

I suggest the following two methods to extract the value between `'<'` and `'>'`:

```
public String extract(final String str) {
    if (str.startsWith("</")) {
        return extract(str, 2);
    } else if (str.startsWith("<")) {
        return extract(str, 1);
    }
    return str;
}

private String extract(final String str, final int offset) {
    return str.substring(str.indexOf('<') + offset, str.lastIndexOf('>'));
}
```

As you can see, the first method evaluates the correct *offset* for the second method to cut off either "offset. Mind that I wrote `str.indexOf('<') + offset` which behaves differently, than your `str.indexOf('<' + offset)`.

To fix your first problem, store the result of `scan.next()` and replace *all* occurrences with that temporary string:

```
final String token = scan.next();
if (token.startsWith("</")) { // removed the second argument
    final String currentTag = extract(token); // renamed variable
    final String lastTag = htmlTag.pop(); // introduced a new temporary variable
    if (!lastTag.equals(currentTag)) {
        isBalanced = false;
    }
}
else if (token.startsWith("<")) {
    htmlTag.push(extract(token)); // no need for a variable here
}
```

I guess this should help you to fix your problems. You can also improve that code a little bit more, for example try to avoid calling `#startsWith("</")` and `#startsWith("<")` twice.

Comment: Thank everyone for the help.  I ended up fixing it last night.  I just made tempString = scan.next() and did all evaluations with that.